# Regular Tree Languages are closed under quotient?

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, automata-theory, tree

The [Wikipedia page for Regular Tree Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_tree_grammar) notes that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular tree languages, than $L_1 \setminus L_2$ is as well. However, it doesn't define this quotient operation for trees, and doesn't give a reference for this specific fact.

I'm wondering if someone can point me to a formal definition of the quotient operaiton on tree languages, and a proof that they are indeed closed under this operation.

Comment: Are you sure that the symbol is not intended to denote set difference?

Comment: @JanJohannsen... derp. Yep, that's probably exactly what it is.